Calendar control in WPF is unselecting dates on control shift click
I have a WPF application with the following control within it:
<Expander x:Name="Expander" FontSize="10" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, ElementName=calendarExpander}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Collapsed">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseEnterCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Expanded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeaveCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Expander.Header>
        <Label FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
            <Label.Content>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy} to {1:dd/MM/yyyy}">
                            <Binding Path="StartDate" ElementName="calendarExpander" />
                            <Binding Path="EndDate" ElementName="calendarExpander" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </Label.Content>
        </Label>
    </Expander.Header>
    <Calendar x:Name="Calendar" SelectionMode="SingleRange" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, ElementName=calendarExpander}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDatesChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDates, ElementName=Calendar}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Calendar>
</Expander>

The control work exactly as I expect unless I ctrl + shift click the start and end date. Here it will select the dates as we would expect but the control seems to hold focus and when I click anywhere else the SelectedDates of the control change to only whatever StartDate was clicked.
See the below gif for a demo of this happening. The gif shows me drag clicking the selection and then clicking on the side of the control. Then I ctrl + shift click the start and end dates and click the side of the control.
In the first instance we see the expected behaviour of it keeping the dates selected but in the second the dates unselect and it changes to only selecting the start date.

Does anyone have any idea how to stop this from happening?

Re: "any idea". It works for "MultipleRange" ... but then you would have to inform the user that "selecting multiple ranges" is not allowed if he attempts to submit more than one range. And / or, you intercept their keystrokes and selection changes and manage the process. Not the solution you're looking for, but it's not the first time I've encountered controls that did not behave as expected; or left artifacts; etc.
